# is it possible to create stored procedure at runtime using spring jpa hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to create a stored procedure using spring jpa hibernate..I searched on net but all says about invoking or calling procedure ..

I have a  multiple db but procedure are same for All ,I want create/drop Stored procedure at runtime .

I am using Annotation based approach for spring jpa
can I create a store procedure using jpa hibernate.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [native query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html) feature of hibernate to perform any sql you want.